# Bicloven bifibrations via adjoints to reindexing functors

Tags: category-theory

In "Categorical Logic and Type Theory" by Bart Jacobs, in the proof of Lemma 9.1.2. Jacobs uses that $\mathbb E_u(X,Y) \cong \mathbb E_{\operatorname{Cod}(u)}(\coprod_u(X),Y)$ naturally in $X,Y$ for all $u$ if and only, if $p : \mathbb E \to \mathbb B$ is a opfibration (it was assumed that $p$ is a fibration, I don't know whether this changes something).

I tried proving the dual statement for Cartesian morphisms but all I seem to get given such natural isomorphisms are *weak* Cartesian lifts. I don't see why they should be stable under compositions.

Ultimately the goal is to prove that a bicloven bifibration is equivalently given by a cleavage and left-adjoints to the induced reindexing functors.

So what am I missing here to make this work?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking: why should a cloven opfibration be a bifibration as soon as every $u_!$ as a right adjoint ? (where $X \to u_! X$ denotes the chosen cocartesian lifts above $u$)

Comment: @Pece Yes. Ideally though, I would like to use the fact that I have weakly cocartesian lifts, since I have proved that already.

Comment: I assume your last comment refers to weakly cartesian lifts (not cocartesian, as you have an opfibration, those already exist and are strict). I will type an answer tonight if I find time, but I'm pretty sure you can show that the weak cartesian lifts are actual cartesian lifts (assuming the weak one you found above $u$ are of the form $u^\ast Y \to u_!u^\ast Y \to Y$ where the last map is the counit of the given adjunction): if you have two maps above $v$ that are equalized by $u^\ast Y \to Y$, you can push above $vu$ and then use the adjunction $u_! \dashv u^\ast$.

Comment: @StefanPerko I did prove in my answer that, in an opfibration, weakly cartesian morphisms are cocartesian, hence that an obfibration with weakly cartesian lifts is a bifibration. I should perhaps rewrite my answer for clarity?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov No, I'm sorry. That I don't respond does not mean that I'm dissatisfied with your answer, I just don't always have the time (and sometimes knowledge) to review everything immediately. Differing notation can also make this take longer. - Unless that is not what you meant, then nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have spotted a gap in Jacobs' proof, as it shows only that weak (cloven) fibrations are weak bifbrations if and only if their reindexing functors have left adjoints. The reason a gap in a fibration argument may produce a weak fibration argument is that a weak fibration is a functor the restriction of which to the preimage of any subcategory of the form $\circlearrowright\to\circlearrowright$ is a fibration. Consequently, a fibration argument that does not mention composition of cartesian morphisms will only be valid for weak fibrations.

Nevertheless, it is true that being a fibration ensures $p$-weakly cocartesian morphisms are cocartesian. I'll prove the dual statement using the following relativization of the notion of cartesian.

**Definition.** Relative to a functor $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$, we say that a morphism $B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C\in\mathcal F$ over $Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\in\mathcal C$ (i.e. with $p\gamma=g$) is **$f$-cartesian** for a morphism $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\in\mathcal C$ if every $A\xrightarrow{\eta}C$ over $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ factors uniquely as $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ with $p\phi=f$.
A morphism in $\mathcal F$ is called **weak cartesian** if it is $\mathrm{id}$-cartesian, and **cartesian** if it is $f$-cartesian for every morphism $f$ with appropriate codomain. Dually, we say that a morphism is **$f$-cocartesian** if it is $f$-cartesian relative to the dual functor $\mathcal C^{op}\xleftarrow{p^{op}}\mathcal F^{op}$.

To get a feel for this relativization, consider what happens to the pullback lemma.

**Lemma** (Generalized Pullback lemma). Given a pair of morphism $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ over $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ and a morphism $W\xrightarrow{h}X$, any two of the following properties imply the third:

1. $\phi$ is $h$-cartesian
2. $\gamma\circ\phi$ is $h$-cartesian
3. $\gamma$ is $f\circ h$-cartesian

In particular, cartesian morphisms are closed under composition and post-cacnelation.

*Proof.* Assume 3., that $\gamma$ is $f\circ h$-cartesian. Then post-composition with $B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ gives a bijection between morphisms $D\to C$ over $W\xrightarrow{h}X\xrightarrow{g\circ f}Z$ and morphisms $D\to B$ over $W\xrightarrow{h}X\xrightarrow{f}Y$. Because post- and pre-composition commute, we obtain the equivalence of 1. and 2. 
Conversely, assume 1. and 2., and note that a morphism $D\to C$ over $W\xrightarrow{f\circ h}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ factors as $D\to A\xrightarrow{\gamma\circ\phi}C$, and that a morphism $D\to B$ over $W\xrightarrow{h}X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ factors uniquely as $D\to A\xrightarrow{\phi}B$.

**Definition.** We say that a morphism $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\in\mathcal C$ has **$g$-cocartesian lifts** for a morphism $Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\in\mathcal C$ if for every object $A\in\mathcal F$ over $X\in\mathcal C$ there is a $g$-cocartesian morphism $A\xrightarrow{\phi'}B'\in\mathcal F$ over $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\in\mathcal C$. We say that $\mathcal C\xleftarrow{p}\mathcal F$ is an **opfibration** if every morphism in $\mathcal C$ has cocartesian lifts.

**Lemma.** A weak cartesian $B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ over $Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ is $f$-cartesian if $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ has $g$-cocartesian lifts. In particular, weak cartesian morphisms in an opfibiration are cartesian morphisms.

*Proof.* If $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ has a $g$-cocartesian lift $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B'$, then any $A\xrightarrow{\eta}C$ over $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ factors uniquely as $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B'\xrightarrow{\gamma'}C$ with $p\gamma'=g$. Thus if $B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ is weak cartesian over $Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$, we have a further unique factorization $B'\xrightarrow{\beta}B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$ over $Y\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_Y}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$, hence $A\xrightarrow{\eta}C$ over $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_Y}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ factors uniquely as $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B'\xrightarrow{\beta}B\xrightarrow{\gamma}C$.